# Can the @property directive be used on primitive data types?

Tags: objective-c, properties

In all the example programs I've seen the @property directive is used on object types. For example:

```
 @property NSArray *myArray;
```

My question is, can I use and/or should I use @property on primitive data types such as int? For example:

```
@property int myNumber;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers.  Hey, who gave my question a -1?  What's wrong with my question?

Comment: I downvoted, because if you had read basic Objective-C documents, you would have found the answer yourself.

Comment: Hi Sebastian,  I had been reading a lot of basic objective-c documents and I didn't find the answer.  Very few documents really do a good job at explaining any one topic.  I've ended up using several different resources just to put all the pieces together for a single topic.  I am not stupid or lazy, so please remember how hard it is to learn programming the next time you label something to basic to ask and downvote it. Thank you.

Comment: To Josh, Gabriele, Monolo and MrCode, yes I did find that article "Use of properties in Objective C 2.0 for Primitive types."  However, the article is 3 years old and there may have been changes to how the @property directive works since 3 years ago.  So, I asked the question again to get a more current answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL myBool;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger myCount;
```

`assign` is the directive that tells the compiler and the runtime that your property doesn't need memory management, and values can just be assigned directly to the ivar.

Comment: Assign is the default for primitive types

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.
But you can't use memory related options such as retain/strong/weak for the primitive data types.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. @property is simply a shorthand for a getter and setter method, and works fine for any type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but make sure you use the attribute (assign) for it.